# Is there a programming training dataset for robot program itself

Tags: neural-networks

Where can I find training datasets like the ones provided for linguistic training, but to train a program to program itself.

I want to input this training dataset to a programming script and it should use it to program itself.

What do I need to consider in this kind of artificial intelligence?

Comment: I think for what you want to do, you need to focus more on evolutionary algorithms and reinforcement learning related algorithms. This [link](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/05/using-machine-learning-to-explore.html) might help.

Comment: I feel reinforcement is tedious work and need to write policy for each game, is there a generic method that can apply to all by write once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an open area of research, but it seems to be considered to be untenable given current methods.

[This is relevant, and provides a link to a training set](https://openai.com/requests-for-research/#description2code), but doesn't provide much more beyond that.

Specifically, an assumed requisite of this task is meaning comprehension, which we don't seem to be much closer towards given current methods.

Answer (score 1):

On self improving AI

The way it's been done in the past is one AI turns a picture into text an the other turns text into a picture.

The AI generated material is added to known good material. The AI's job then is to guess what is real an what is fake (generated by AI).

At the point when the AI cannot tell in a false positive way both AI are said to be at their limit. If the limit is good enough you're done otherwise go back and code (more nodes or better function or more real data)

The thing to remember is you still need real data. The act of putting the AI together is good only to create more data then you could ever provide.

If that data is bad then you are going to rely on the cost function more then the data. But this allows you to label data real and AI so if the function rewards identifying the AI the AI's find each other's flaws and the better at avoiding flaws the better the AI get. (You still need real data! just less)

For example if two people cannot play ping pong if they play each other they learn slowly and only the cost function enforces their learning.
But have them play a pro (lots of good data) and they get better much faster.

Comment: I feel this training data is one to many, if focus on problem to solution style training data , can this be one to one ? Where can find these training data? What is the next step after find frequency of words in all programming script?

Comment: The reason say google is good at AI is because of it's ability to label data (reCaptcha).
If you want good a good AI you need good data. you can do it by hand search for what you are looking for but you need data.
It's why Mozilla did this: https://voice.mozilla.org/

Comment: I feel reinforcement programming is tedious because it need to write policy for each game, is there a generic method that can apply to all things it learn?